# pgfplots log axis with only minor ticks/labels

Tags: pgfplots, labels

I'd like generate sheet of blank semilog paper. Every decade shoud have labels from 1 to 9.

I only managed to have an unlabelled axis, but had no success to set the x axis labelling according to my needs.

Here is a M(NW)E:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%  \pgfplotsset{log base 10 number format code/.code={$fun^{\pgfmathprintnumber{#1}}$}}
    \pgfplotsset{log base 10 number format code/.code={10}}
  \begin{semilogxaxis}[
    xmin=1, xmax=100,
    xminorticks=true,
    minor x tick num=9,
%    
    grid=both]
    \addplot {ln(x)};
  \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `extra x ticks` and `extra x tick labels`. However the space for these numbers becomes smaller and smaller. We can take refuge under `x post scale` and enlarge the x axis.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogxaxis}[x post scale=3,
    xmin=1, xmax=1000,
    xticklabels={1,10,100,1000},
    extra x tick style={font=\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont},
    extra x ticks={2,...,9,20,30,...,90,200,300,...,900},
    extra x tick labels={2,...,9,20,30,...,90,200,300,...,900},
    ymin=0,ymax=9,
%
    grid=both]
  \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Earlier answer**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogxaxis}[
    xmin=1, xmax=100000000,
    xticklabels={1,2,...,9},
    ymin=0,ymax=9,
%
    grid=both]
  \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to just use major ticks, and to specify explicitly which ones you need.  You can use `...` in the list of ticks and their labels.  I admit that it's kind of repetitive, but I don't know whether it is possible to shorten this syntax further (in a reasonable way).  For two decades (as in your example) it's ok I guess.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogxaxis}[
    xmin=1, xmax=100,
    xtick={1,2,...,10,20,30,...,100},
    xticklabels={1,2,...,9,1,2,...,9,1},
    grid=both]
    \addplot {ln(x)};
  \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: the output]